New bolded tags?
The past few days, I’ve noticed that the question tags on the main site are now bolded; is there any way to revert them back to normal? (Not the end of the world, but I find it distracting more than anything else.)

Gosh, you're right. It does look a bit ugly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanks,_Obama

More seriously, I suspect it's just one of the endless tweaks to the visuals that SE does. I think here on MO it would be a matter of having a custom user script, I doubt you could go to https://meta.stackexchange.com, raise a question, and see it change back.

Follow the action at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400086/all-tag-labels-suddenly-appear-in-bold-font, where someone already pointed it out

The tag ([meta-tag:design]) seems to be suitable here. Maybe ([meta-tag:tags]), too?

@MartinSleziak Added, thanks as always Martin. And thank you for the updates David; I agree that my chances over at meta se are slim to none, cest la vie.

It could also be something buggy (something like that happened back in 2016, again with boldface tags). Certainly it's been brought to attention since it seems to be network-wide.

@ToddTrimble Clearly, the change was intentional - from David Roberts' link you can get to: Seeking feedback on tag colors update. I have to admit that I did not notice that announcement at the time - despite the fact that it was featured.

I use the following piece of CSS code
.s-tag  {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

to revert the tags back to normal.
